# Stop IntelliJ IDEA Scala worksheet from removing blank lines

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Every time a Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ IDEA is ran, some blank lines are automatically removed from the code. Is there a setting to stop this behavior?

For example:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String)

case class Purchase(product: Int, person: Person)
```

turns into:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
case class Purchase(product: Int, person: Person)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Intellij-idea got the settings for your question.
Navigate through

> Settings > Editor > Code Style

There you will find `Formatter Control` section and enable the formatter markers in the comments check box.

Now you can go to your WorkSheet and add comments like this where you don't really want not to format.

```
// @formatter:off
case class Person(id: Int, name: String)

case class Purchase(product: Int, person: Person)
// @formatter:off
```

Hope it helped.